# Baikal CalDAV : No 'Authorization: Basic' header found ver. 0.6.0 MacOSX Calendar

Tags: caldav, carddav

Previously we were using **[Baikal](https://github.com/sabre-io/Baikal)** ver. 0.5.3, which we tested for Thunderbird and Mac OSX Calendar, recently we upgraded to **ver. 0.6.0, after that Thunderbird is working but Mac OSX Calendar is not working**,

error logs :
user not authorized: Baikal DAV: **No 'Authorization: Basic' header found**. Either the client didn't send one,
or the server is misconfigured. Login was needed for privilege: {DAV:}read on principals/xyz@rediff-inc.com

I am using this URL for MacOSX : **http://domainz.com/cal.php/principals/xyz@domainz.com**

Answer (score 2):

Newer MacOSX doesn't send credentials in Auth header in plain text http request, after enabling TLS on server i.e https, everything worked fine.